# vb.net POST variables

Tags: vb.net, redirect, post

I am performing an integration to a third party site and they have asked me to redirect to their URL with a bunch of POST variables.

The only way I can work out how to do this is by creating an HTML form with hidden fields, and then trigger a JS click event on a button to POST the form to their site.

Ideally I would like to do this from the VB code as the data may be sensitive and there are bits I don't want to render in the client side.

Has anyone any experience of doing this successfully.  I have googled around but can only find ways to use GET variables on the URL or POST and read the response.

Comment: A redirect can't have POST values.  If the POST request needs to come from the client-side then it needs to be as a form post, like you've done.

Comment: So is it possible to POST to another site and divert the client from server side?

Comment: You can POST from server-side code, but the response would be back to the server-side code.  If the user needs to interact with the external site directly, this wouldn't be a workable solution.  If, on the other hand, your site can act as a proxy between the user and the external site then your server-side code can send the POST request, parse the response, and show data from the response to the user.